# Drawing geometry to an SDL_Texture?

Tags: c++, sdl, platformer, level-design

As a direct result of [this question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/75057/which-buffering-process-would-be-more-efficient?noredirect=1#comment136157_75057) that I asked a few days ago, I want to draw potentially-complex geometry to a SDL_Texture or, I suppose, an SDL_Surface. Ultimately, I want the foreground of a 2D platformer on this texture so that I cant draw a specific portion to the screen, as explained in the above link. Most of the geometry will be simple rectangles, but I would also like to draw slopes and possibly circles. Diving into OpenGL seems like a viable option at this point, but if I could avoid it, that would be grand.

Comment: You might be interested in the SDL_gpu library found at https://code.google.com/p/sdl-gpu/ . It looks like it may be a good middle ground between only being able to draw lines and rectangles, and diving fully into OpenGL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`SDL_SetRenderTarget(SDL_Renderer *renderer,SDL_Texture  *texture)`](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_SetRenderTarget)

After calling this, any drawing functions using this renderer will be drawn into the specified texture, instead of to the screen.  (Passing `NULL` for the texture will make subsequent drawing functions draw to the screen again)

Note that the texture must have been created using the `SDL_TEXTUREACCESS_TARGET` flag.

More details are available in [the on-line documentation](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_SetRenderTarget).

Comment: I actually found the same function this morning before looking at stackexchange. Thanks!